# How do I enable a Wordpress site behind a Traefik proxy

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a WordPress site behind a Traefik proxy. WordPress needs to be on a separate port for this to work so I have a VM with ip 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:9280. I have https://my.site.com forwarding to http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:9280. When I try to complete the WordPress installation (where you pick the language) from my.site.com [it appears to have lost the CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7UWW.jpg).
I am using Traefik in TrueNAS redirecting to a VM which I have done successfully with other VMs e.g. Home Assistant and Poste.
Any hints are appreciated!

I have tried various alternatives with no success. What changes do I need to make so that I can access my WordPress site via https://my.site.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work I have to add the following to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://my.site.com/wordpress' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://my.site.com/wordpress' );

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PRO>
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```